# st_read option does not work if parameter is separated from equal (=) sign

Tags: r, encoding, sf

This is a small pet peeve. I'm reading a latin1 encoded shapefile in R using st_read and the encoding option.

I just found out that if I write `encoding=latin1` everything works as expected but, if I write `encoding = latin1` I get a warning message and the encoding is not set correctly.

Is this the expected behavior? Has anyone else noticed this?

Comment: I can't replicate this behaviour with a shapefile of my own. Can you post the whole sequence of commands you've used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These options are passed to the device driver and so are subject to GDAL/OGR driver syntax rules. You don't provide an example but I reckon this is what you are doing:

```
> s = st_read("./crop.shp", options="encoding=latin1", quiet=TRUE)

> s = st_read("./crop.shp", options="encoding = latin1", quiet=TRUE)
Warning message:
In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, as.character(options), quiet, type,  :
  GDAL Message 6: driver ESRI Shapefile does not support open option encoding
```

Why? Because that's the way it is. I suspect its because GDAL maybe supports options as flags for some of the drivers, but this parameter needs a value and so has to be `key=value` with no spaces.

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing. So it looks like it't just how GDAL works. Will keep an eye for extra spaces when using st_read...